# Can't see changes in Mounted volumes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a deployment with specific mounts (please refer to pod dscription below).

But whenever I write into the specified directory in the container it isn't shown in the host folder.

For example:

```
$ kubectl exec owncloud-68c956f65c-cpxp4 -- ls /var/www/html/data

admin
avatars
files_external
index.html
owncloud.db
owncloud.log

$ ls /disk1/owncloud
...nothing...
```

Here is the pod full description:

```
Name:               owncloud-68c956f65c-cpxp4
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               k8s-worker-01/192.168.0.2
Start Time:         Mon, 27 May 2019 11:12:03 +0100
Labels:             app=owncloud
                    pod-template-hash=68c956f65c
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.40.0.4
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/owncloud-68c956f65c
Containers:
  owncloud:
    Container ID:   docker://68d8d96833635927e0317b849a59539cd8f119231a3a41b3a7be4deb5914aa9c
    Image:          owncloud:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://owncloud@sha256:173811cb4c40505401595a45c39a802b89fb476885b3f6e8fe327aae08d20fe8
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 27 May 2019 11:12:13 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7b4bw (ro)
      /var/www/html/config from config (rw)
      /var/www/html/data from data (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home/pi/owncloud/owncloud_conf
    HostPathType:  Directory
  data:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /disk1/owncloud
    HostPathType:  Directory
  default-token-7b4bw:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-7b4bw
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

What's wrong here ?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam

Comment: Into which directory on the container?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel It's written in my post :)

Comment: Can you please post the kubernetes descriptor?

Comment: What's the descriptor ? @MatthewLDaniel

Comment: The `Deployment`, `StatefulSet`, `Pod`, or other descriptor that describes those `volumes:` and the associated `volumeMounts:`; it would be `kubectl get -o yaml pod owncloud-68c956f65c-cpxp4` (or another Pod name if that one has already exited)

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud could you please add information pointed by Matthew L Daniel?
It will help troubleshooting.

Comment: I edited my post :) @PjoterS

Comment: 1) Can you write to the dir on host directly?; 2) After `sync` command, will it work?; 3) Please provide the disk mount info of that dir by `cat /proc/self/mountinfo`

Comment: 1) yes as user `pi` : `drwxr-xr-x 2 pi   pi   4096 Jun  5 10:53 .`; 2) after sync, it doesn't work; 3) `177 15 8:1 / /disk1 rw,relatime shared:136 - ext4 /dev/sda1 rw,data=ordered` @menya

Comment: Can you confirm that you are running the command `ls` at the same exact node your pod is running (`k8s-worker-01/192.168.0.2`) ?

Comment: @gonzalesraul Am I supposed to? The hard drive is plugged into the master node ! Do I have to specify to run the pod into the master node then?

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud it is not advised to run pods on master unless you know what you are doing, workloads should goes on worker nodes. The HostPath volumes must be on the node where the pod is running, it is not the ideal way to persists info but if you need to use that make sure to use pod affinity to the node (or nodeSelector). Check more about the volume hostpath on the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the message exchanged, the directory `/disk1/owncloud` resides on the `master node`, the pod described on your question shows that the type of volume used is [hostpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), and it was scheduled for another node (`k8s-worker-01/192.168.0.2`) that does not have the hostpath informed.

To fix that you should consider move the mount point for a worker node (unless you want to run the pod on master) and use rules for [pod affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature) or [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector).

If you want a resilient solution for storage (replicas, distribution among different nodes), I would recommend to use:

- [rook.io](https://rook.io): Really great, good docs and coverage different aspects of storage (block,file,object and for different backends ...)
- [gluster-block](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-block): it is a plug-in for gluster storage, this is used combined with heketi. See docs [k8s provisioning](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/gluster-block-provisioning.md)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I decided to set up a resilient solution for storage. I tried implementing rook. The problem is that I'm running an ARM based cluster (Rpi) and the last rook image which support ARM is the v0.6.0. But, I can't make it work.... Do you suggest another simpler solution for this kind of setup ? (I mainly want to host my private cloud and a media server)